# Submit Form Equivalent To WML

Tags: forms, form-submit, wap, wml

I'm playing a little bit with WML with PHP, then I want to know what is the equivalent of this on WML 1.0:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post">
<label for="file">File:</label><br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WML 1.0 is deprecated about 10 years ago, but I will answer this by looking at the spec for wml1.0 from [www.wapforum.org/what/technical/wml-30-apr-98.pdf](http://www.wapforum.org/what/technical/wml-30-apr-98.pdf)

But do note that the "file" input type isn't supported by all devices, so the chances of this actually working is quite slim.

```
<WML>
<CARD>
<DO TYPE="ACCEPT">
<GO URL="/upload_file.php" />
</DO>
<FIELDSET TITLE="File">
File: <INPUT TYPE="FILE" KEY="myfile"/>
</FIELDSET>
</CARD>
</WML>
```